# How to sanitize a string of text containing ampersands for comparison to another string of text

Tags: php, preg-replace

Because there are multiple ways of encoding "special" characters, in particular the ampersand, how would one do a string comparison that removes all special characters from both the needle and the haystack to allow for an "apples to apples" comparison to check that the needle appears in the haystack?

For example, if I have a needle "black & decker", and I want to sanitize it down to "black decker" and then see if "black decker" appears in the haystack, I will need to do the same replacement I did on needle to haystack in order to account for all ways of encoding the ampersand and how "black & decker" might be encoded to appear in the haystack.

```
&amp;
&amp;amp; (I've only seen this in WordPress editor markup)
&#038
```

Is there a preg_replace, regex or replacement method that can do this with some degree of accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want to reduce the string down to just letters, numbers and spaces? For that I'd use
`preg_replace('/[^\w\d ]/', '')`
which basically eliminates anything that's not a "word character", digit, or space

Comment: What if the haystack (or the needle for that matter) is stored as "black &amp; decker", replaced string will be "black amp decker", no?

Comment: true, I forgot about that. In that case, pass the string through `htmlspecialchars_decode()` first.

It's hard to make something like this universal, you just have to be aware of the different encodings that you may encounter along the way

Comment: I'm getting this > Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: another one to watch out for in some older PHP is magic quotes. If `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` returns true, any quotes in form input will be escaped with a backslash. You can then use `stripslashes()` to get rid of those. 

The magic quotes feature was added to prevent SQL injection, but was recently removed because it's pretty annoying and there are better ways of dealing with the SQL injection problem.

Comment: oops, I think you can just drop the `g` modifier at the end, because `preg_replace` already does a global search and replace

Comment: Done! Thanks. Any way to include "periods" in the regex?